# Resize browser window with JS/Jquery on website access

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, resize

I have my first website made some months ago, and it is not responsive. I have built it on 1280x1024px so on larger or smaller screens we can't see it resposnive. Now, on smaller screens it's ok, I'm not interesting in that, but I have a question: is it possible on larger screens, like 1680x1050px when I open this site to automatically resize the browser window to 1280x1024px with JS or Jquery ? Some code to bring the browser to 1280x1024px instead of full-screen of monitor resolution on larger screen ?

Thanks.

Comment: If this was possible (which it isn't) it would be incredibly bad practice. You shouldn't solve a problem by restricting your users. Spend your time solving the problem in a positive way, not by hiding the shortcomings.

Comment: Just put a `max-width: 1280px;` to your body or main container in  your CSS file.

Comment: Could you rewrite the question to state the underlying problem that you think resizing is a good way to fix. Which it probably isn't. What's the actual underlying problem on a large screen? I suspect Vincent's solution will be the answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the resizeTo function.

Here's a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp) to show how it works